# What does linear regime of nonlinearity mean in normalisation?

Tags: neural-networks, batch-normalization, normalisation

In section 3 paragraph 2 of *Batch Normalization: Accelerating Deep Network Training b y Reducing Internal Covariate Shift* paper (https://arxiv.org/abs/1502.03167) they say that normalizing a layer's input may change what it represents, I understand this. But what do they mean in the bolded part?

> For instance, normalizing the inputs of a sigmoid would constrain them
> to the **linear regime of the nonlinearity**.

Answer (score 2):

The normalization makes the signal small enough to remain in the region of the sigmoid that can be well approximated by a straight line.

The idea is the same as in electronics: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small-signal_model

Comment: Oh so near the range of around [-1, 1] on the horizontal axis where the slope is close to being a straight line?

Comment: Yes, that's it. The sigmoid is also almost linear, flat, for large absolute values. The hard sigmoid is a piecewise linear approximation to the sigmoid based on these three regions: large negative, around zero, large positive.